# I don't have the folder "assets" - Eclipse

Tags: android, eclipse, assets

a simple question.. In my project I don't have the assets folder .. I don't know if I've deleted it..

Should I only to create the folder?? Do I need to do anything else?

Thank you.

Comment: An asset folder contains nothing you can see in other projects hence you can copy one of the folders to the package..

Comment: Thank yoy @Dibya.. Can I create a new folder?

Comment: In eclipse's project explorer, if you have any other project then simply click and drag it. Make sure you are holding Ctrl key or it will cut the folder..

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yes, just create the folder.  Your project will be built appropriately.